# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query for returning only one element

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'am writing a method to retrieve an element of a DB giving a Long id parameter.

This id is unique, so the method should just return one element, and I want to create a class instance with this element retrived.

I've made the following method that works perfectly fine:

```
@Override
public ElementEntity getElement(final long id)
{
    final MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramSource.addValue("element_id", id);
    final List<ElementEntity > listOfElements =
        namedParameterJdbcOperations.query(SQL_RETURN_ELEMENT_BY_ID, paramSource, ROW_MAPPER_ELEMENT);
    return !listOfElements .isEmpty() ? listOfElements.get(0) : null;
}
```

The ROW_MAPPER is implemented this way:

```
private static final RowMapper<ElementEntity > ROW_MAPPER_INSTALLER =
    (rs, RowNum) ->
        new ElementEntityBuilder().setElement(rs.getBytes("ELEMENT")).build();
```

The element is a byte array. I repeat, works perfectly. But I would like to avoid using a list and retrieving the first position and, instead, create directly the ElementEntity. So I tried the following approach:

```
 @Override
public ElementEntity getElement(final long id)
{
    final MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramSource.addValue("element_id", id);

    return namedParameterJdbcOperations.query(SQL_RETURN_ELEMENT_BY_ID, paramSource, (ResultSet rs) -> new DesktopAppInstallerEntity(rs.getBytes("ELEMENT")));
}
```

Althought I have't made any more changes, it gives me the following error:`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: No data is available`.

That's the full error (I changed some words to avoid showing the real SQL query):

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT SOMETHING FROM SOMEWHERE WHERE id = ?]; No data is available [2000-200]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: No data is available [2000-200]
```

I'm pretty new to all this JDBC, but it seems to me that the paramSource is not working properly when I apply this changes and I don't have the foggiest idea why is happening because I'm just changing the result extractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself. I will share my answer to help the community. I used `NamedParameterJdbcOperations.queryForObject` instead of `namedParameterJdbcOperations.query` and used the same ROW_MAPPER:

```
@Override
public ElementEntity getElement(final long id)
{
    final MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramSource.addValue("id", id);

    try
    {
        return namedParameterJdbcOperations.queryForObject(SQL_RETURN_ELEMENT, paramSource, ROW_MAPPER_ELEMENT);
    }
    catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In my particular case I'm interested to catch when the SQL Query attempt to find an Element that doesn't exist in the DB. For this purpose I catch and handle the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` thrown.

More info could be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-